# Using 3rd party library's callbacks (no file descriptor) in an event-driven / asynchronous framework

Tags: c++, events, asynchronous

The goal is to have a single-threaded event-driven framework. The end-user will do something like:

```
class MyEventFramework : public EventFramework {
protected:
  virtual void onData (const Data& data);
  virtual void onReport (const Report& report);
  virtual void onUserRequest (const UserRequest& userRequest);
...
};
```

There are other components behind the scenes, like a series of timers, etc.

Most of these handlers are called by my own code, so I can use `select()` or a similar concept (`kqueue()`, `epoll()`, etc) over a series of **file descriptors**.

My issue is that the `onData()` routine is actually a callback from a third-party library, which I don't have the source code for. Therefore, I can't just use their **file descriptor**; I only know that something has happened via the callback.

Right now I have a multithreaded implementation of my framework; the logic leading up to `onData()` occurs in a separate thread before reaching the user. This is undesirable because it necessitates error-prone mutex locks, requires expensive thread switching (this is a low-latency application), and other problems. (To clarify, each handler in the framework must be atomic with respect to each other because of the potential for race conditions in the client application.)

Has anyone else encountered this before and lived to tell the tale?

Comment: Standard fare in any GUI app, all notifications are asynchronous.  A message queue and a dispatch loop are essential ingredients.  PostMessage to marshal thread notifications.

Comment: @Hans Yeah, I'd thought about using a queue as well. I was hoping there'd be a way to have a file descriptor for `select()`. (Like a FIFO, almost, but without needing a pipe outside the process.)

Comment: what OS's do you need to support?

Comment: @Lou Linux required. Mac OS X would be nice, but not required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly : your dispatching thread is blocked on some system call (say `select` or `poll`), and you would like the `onData` member function to follow the same notification path.

Using a [pipe](http://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe) seems like a good solution to me without hurting the design too much :

- `select` monitors one end of the pipe
- the 3rd library callbacks 'rings' the other end of the pipe when called

This allows for a 'thread jump', the only issue being that the pipe should only be used as a notification facility : the parameter to the `onData` function will have to be queued somewhere between the pipe notification and the processing thread wake-up.

Comment: I certainly entertained the idea of a pipe or FIFO. There's still the issue of synchronizing the `onData` parameter structure if the pipe is only used for notification. I'll have to think it over some. Thanks for your response!

Comment: You could create a copy of the Data structure on the heap in the onData function. So you don't need to care about synchronisation since the copy is owned by the main thread. If the performance of the enque/dequeue operation (this operations need to be locked by a mutex) matters to you you could use a nonblocking fifo.

Answer (score 2):

I'm partial to self-connected local UDP sockets (ie. bound to INADDR_LOOPBACK, then connected to same address). At that point your callback can write to the socket, either a single byte (for a simple wakeup), or a message with the callback's data.

Comment: The inter-thread communication theme (pipes, sockets) seems to be a pretty popular answer to my question. I'll have to ponder this some more.